# Create ajax handlers for form inside jquery toggled panel - in case of errors, panel should stay visibile

Tags: ajax, forms, authentication, jquery

I have a dropdown panel in a menu which is a div toggled by jquery - so it's not visibile by default and on page refresh returns to display:none

In this div I have a form which executes login functions. If there's a error on the form (bad password, invalid username, empty fields), the form returns errors accordingly with messages displayed next to the fields containing errors.

However, since the form is contained into a toggled div, when the page is refreshed after submit, the whole div naturally disappears. If the login passes, it's not a problem because a redirect occurs. But if the login has errors, the errors are visible only if the user clicks on the panel again, making it visible again.

How to keep the div panel toggled in case of form errors?

the content of the panel are like this :

```
<ul id="signin-menu" class="sub-menu" style="display: none">
    <div class="login" id="login-form-<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>">
        <?php $template->the_errors(); ?>
        <form name="loginform" id="loginform<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" action="<?php $template->the_action_url( 'login' ); ?>" method="post">
                <p class="login-username">
                    <label for="user_login<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Nome utente', 'salgari' ) ?></label>
                    <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" value="<?php $template->the_posted_value( 'log' ); ?>" />
                </p>
                <p class="login-password">
                    <label for="user_pass<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Password', 'salgari' ) ?></label>
                    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" class="input" value="" />
                </p>
                <?php do_action( 'login_form' ); 
                      do_action_ref_array( 'tml_login_form', array( &$template ) ); ?>
                <p class="login-remember">
                    <input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" value="forever" />
                    <label for="rememberme<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>"><?php _e( 'Ricordati di me', 'salgari' ); ?></label>
                </p>
                <p class="login-submit">
                    <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" value="<?php _e( 'Collegati', 'salgari' ); ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php $template->the_redirect_url( 'login' ); ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="instance" value="<?php $template->the_instance(); ?>" />
                </p>
        </form>
        <div class="login-actions">
            <?php $template->the_action_links( array( 'login' => false ) ); ?>
        <div>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: use ajax. $.post in jQuery for example.

Comment: thanks, but I've been suggested by the author of a wordpress plugin I'm using a better solution - to check whether errors are created in the form and, if it's the case, toggle the div to visibile:

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 if ( $('#signin-menu').find('.error').length > 0 )
  $('#signin-menu').slideToggle();
});